# How can I extend conduit out from an exterior wall slightly?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, exterior, conduit

I'm replacing an exterior light fixture with an outlet to use to power string lights on a patio. The issue I'm facing is the exterior junction box I obtained can't screw onto the conduit as it's mostly recessed into the wall, and there's a lip that interferes with the rest of it. I was planning on attaching the box to a mounting block to even out the lip (PVC trim or whatever I can get that matches the flashing), but I don't know how to 'extend' the threaded connection so it can connect to the junction box. Is there some magic part I should look for in the store, or should I get a different type of box to mount?

[image: box to install]
[image: conduit exposed]

Other code stuff if concerned: I've swapped out the standard breaker for a GFCI one (can't use a GFCI outlet 8' in the air).

Comment: Is enlarging the hole in the cladding to gain a bit of space for a fitting an option?

Comment: Possibly, what sort of fitting? I'm kinda conservative when it comes to putting holes in the exterior, but the light fixture that was there was already super sketchy

Comment: Some sort of threaded coupling so that you can get a nipple from that to the hub, basically.  Also, the conduit's metal, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Female to male PVC connector?**

[image]

[source](https://www.lowes.com/pd/LASCO-3-4-in-x-3-4-in-x-3-4-in-dia-x-2-in-L-Riser-PVC-Fitting/3371216?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-google-_-lia-_-142-_-pressurepipeandfittings-_-3371216-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=Cj0KCQjw78yFBhCZARIsAOxgSx0MWYoP3X3MsXF68S2TJbqia4S9N-NUtNLPj0eqch9gRW8eWryd2gwaAlCgEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Maybe this?  Thread wires thru, screw female part onto what you have coming out of the wall and there is your protruding threaded male part with wires protruding.  I invariably get the wrong one first time so bring your new box to the hardware store to make sure it will attach.

Comment: To keep a ground connection, would I need to fish a new wire back to the switch box?

Comment: There is no ground wire in your picture and the condulet shown is plastic so if code requires a ground you will need to do just that.

Comment: You might be wrong about the conduit being plastic - pictures can mislead.

Comment: Yeah to me that looks like it could be zinc alloy.  A rigid coupling and nipple achieve similar effect in metal.  Make sure they're of a metal suitable for outdoor use.

Comment: It's a metal conduit (I'm in Chicago, required everywhere), seems like the conduit is rigidly attached to the threads somehow